# Point style in ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

In `ListPointPlot3D`, it seems the only point style available is the default, because there is no `PlotMarkers` option for this function. Is there a way to change the point style? For example, what if I want to draw the points as small cubes?

Comment: And where such arrow should be directed to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
lpdata = Table[(4 π - t) {Cos[t + π/2], Sin[t + π/2], 0} + {0, 0, t}, {t, 0, 4 π, .1}];

lpp1 = ListPointPlot3D[lpdata, 
        Filling -> Bottom,  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", BoxRatios -> 1, 
        FillingStyle -> Directive[LightGreen, Thick, Opacity[.5]],  ImageSize -> 400];
```

**ListPointPlot3D: Post-process Point into Cone**

```
lpp2 = lpp1 /. Point[x__] :> (Sequence@{EdgeForm[], Cone[#, .3]} &@
            ({x} /. {{a_, b_, c_}} :> {{a, b, c}, {a, b, .5 + c}}));

Row[{lpp1, lpp2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

... or into `Cuboid`s

```
lpp1 /. Point -> Cuboid
```

[image]

**DiscretePlot3D: use `lpdata` to define a function and use the option PlotMarkers**

```
ClearAll[foo];
(foo[Sequence @@ #[[1]]] = #[[2]]) & /@ (lpdata /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c});
(* or  (foo[Sequence @@ #1] = #2) & @@@ (lpdata /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c})*) 
 DiscretePlot3D[foo[x, y], {x, lpdata[[All, 1]]}, {y, lpdata[[All, 2]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 400, BoxRatios -> 1, ExtentSize -> 1/5, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"Sphere", Medium}]
```

[image]

(Unfortunately, `Point` and `Sphere` seem to be the only markers that work with `DiscretePlot3D`.)

**BubbleChart3D: append `lpdata` with `1`s and use the options ChartElements or ChartElementFunction**

```
bcdata = {##, 1} & @@@ lpdata;
opts = {ImageSize -> 300, BubbleSizes -> {0.025, .025},
       ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ColorFunction -> (#3 &)};
```

Use the built-in glyphs  with the option `ChartElementFunction`:

```
Row[BubbleChart3D[bcdata, Evaluate@opts,
   ChartElementFunction -> #] & /@ {"Cone", "Cube","TriangleWaveCube"}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

or use the option `ChartElements` and provide your own graphics objects:

```
Row[BubbleChart3D[bcdata, Evaluate@opts, ChartElements -> Graphics3D[#]] & /@ 
       {Cone[], Cuboid[], PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, especially the direct "lpp1 /. Point -> Cuboid"

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use `Graphics3D`. For example (one with `Cuboid`, one with `Sphere`):

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {20, 3}]; 
{Graphics3D[{Blue, Cuboid[#, # + .3 {1, 1, 1}] & /@ pts}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[#, 0.2] & /@ pts}]}
```

[image]